# Convert object to ul li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a list of object in array

```
var myLevel = ['sub', 'topic', 'type']

var myCollection = new Array();
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 1', topic: 'topic 1', type: 'mcq'});
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 1', topic: 'topic 1', type: 'mcq'});
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 1', type: 'fib', topic: 'topic 2'});
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 1', topic: 'topic 1', type: 'mtf'});
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 1', topic: 'topic 1', type: 'mcq'});
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 2', type: 'mcq', topic: 'topic 1'});
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 2', topic: 'topic 1', type: 'mcq'});
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 2', topic: 'topic 1', type: 'mcq'});
```

I want to convert these things in to proper list with ul and li, also the levels of listing is dependent on myLevel variable.

- Book 1

  - topic 1

    - mcq
    - mtf
  - topic 2

    - fib
- Book 2

  - topic 1

    - mcq

Every section has a unique children, it cannot have same.

I have tried of creating element into a loop of myCollection

```
for(var i=0; i<myCollection.length; i++)
{
    for(var j=0; j<myLevel.length; j++)
    {
        createMyTree(myCollection[i][myLevel[j]);
    }
}


function createMyTree(str)
{
     //?????????????
}
```

please help how do i create element on the level needed.

Comment: use nested array(Book =>Topics=>Type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems after a lot effort i have got my answer with some trick.

```
var $out;
$(document).ready(function()
{

    for(var i=0; i<myCollection.length; i++)
    {
        $out = $('#out');
        for(var j=0; j<levelTree.length; j++)
        {
            var itemName = myCollection[i][levelTree[j]];
            var level = j;

            /**********************************************************/


                var $con;
                if($out.children().eq(0).length == 0)
                {
                    $con = $('<ul></ul>');
                    $con.append('<li>'+ itemName + '</li>');
                    $out.append($con);
                }
                else
                {
                    var flag = $out.children().eq(0).children().filter(function(i, e)
                    {
                         return (this.childNodes[0].textContent == itemName);
                    });
                    console.log(flag.length);
                    if(flag.length == 0)
                    {
                        $out.children().eq(0).append('<li>' + itemName + '</li>');
                    }
                }

                var ele = $out.children(0).eq(0).children().filter(function(i, e)
                {
                    return (this.childNodes[0].textContent == itemName);
                }).get();
                $out = $(ele);


            /**********************************************************/
        }
    }
});
```

This can be made more efficient by recursive. But it works fire. :D

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rx4hvn/kL1kud34/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so i redid it and it works unless for one problem: topic 1 get's split up to two topic 1's because topic 2 get's inserted between them.

```
var myLevel = ['sub', 'topic', 'type'];

var myCollection = new Array();
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 1', topic: 'topic 1', type: 'mcq'});
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 1', topic: 'topic 1', type: 'mcq'});
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 1', type: 'fib', topic: 'topic 2'});
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 1', topic: 'topic 1', type: 'mtf'});
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 1', topic: 'topic 1', type: 'mcq'});
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 2', type: 'mcq', topic: 'topic 1'});
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 2', topic: 'topic 1', type: 'mcq'});
myCollection.push({sub: 'Book 2', topic: 'topic 1', type: 'mcq'});

var dom="<ul>";
var used = new Array();
var currentItems = new Array(myLevel.length);
var lastJ = -1;

for(var i=0; i<myCollection.length; i++)
{
    var con = false;
    for(var k=0; k<used.length; k++){
        if(compareObjects(used[k], myCollection[i]))
            con = true;
    }
    if(!con){
        for(var j=0; j<myLevel.length; j++){
            if(currentItems[j] !== myCollection[i][myLevel[j]]){
                if(lastJ !== -1){
                    for(var l=0; l<lastJ-j; l++){
                        dom+="</ul></li>";   
                    }
                }
                for(var l=j+1; l<currentItems.length; l++)
                    currentItems[l] = "";
                currentItems[j] = myCollection[i][myLevel[j]];
                dom+="<li>"+currentItems[j]+(j<myLevel.length-1?"<ul>":"");
                lastJ = j;
            }
        }
        used.push(myCollection[i]);
    }
}
dom+="</ul>";
$('body').html(dom);

function compareObjects(obj1, obj2){
    if(obj1.length != obj2.length)
        return false;
    for(var el in obj1){
        if(obj2[el] === undefined)
            return false;
        if(obj1[el] !== obj2[el])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but list in any ul should be unique, it should not repeat. Also it be dependent on myLevel variable, for nesting levels.

Comment: Is it necessary that there are duplicates in the array or can they be removed?

Comment: yes. its compulsory as i need to make tree structure. Eventually i cannot change myCollection, it can be anything and its level can be gained from myLevel variable.

Comment: Sorry that took me so long, but it's a pretty tough question

Comment: exactly what i wanted. Thanks a lot Markai :)

Comment: seems, book 1 has two "topic 1". That should be merged :(